# SQL Date Variables in Python

Tags: python, sql

I am writing a query inside a Python script.The query is as follows:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
query1 = """select max(date_time) from tablename"""
cur.execute(queryy1)
conn.commit()
rows = cur.fetchall()
print rows
```

Until here the code works fine and gives me the date in some format of the kind datetime.datetime[...]
Now,I want to use this variable 'rows' in another sql query,say,of the following kind:

```
query2="""insert into table xyz(select * from abc where date_time = '%s')"""%(rows)
cur.execute(query2)
```

This gives me an error which is as follows:

```
DataError:invalid input syntax for type timestamp : "[((datetime.datetime(2014,6,6,23,0),)]"
```

I am totally new to learning Python. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried the following and it worked:

```
query2 ="""insert into table xyz(select * from abc where date_time = %s)"""
cur.execute(query2,(rows))
```

Comment: Please add the error message to your question, otherwise, we can only guess as to what the reason is.

Comment: Edited the Question with error message

Comment: Well, got the solution. Updating it in the question. Though, I have no idea why this worked and the earlier one didn't

Comment: It worked because in the first try you did the formatting yourself, ending up inserting a list where a conversion to a datetime should take place, while in the second you let the `execute` method do it for you, but the right way.

Comment: @Nisha It is recommended that you move your edit with the solution into an answer on its own, so people see it as a solution and can vote on it. You will also be able to (and should) accept your own answer as the solution.

Comment: @Nisha I have made a community wiki in case if you don't post you answer and accept it! If you want to post your own answer and to accept it just post it, and I shall remove the wiki!

Comment: @korem please have a look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353029/storing-output-of-sql-query-in-python-variable)

Comment: @ρss please have a look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353029/storing-output-of-sql-query-in-python-variable)

Comment: @androyd please have a look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353029/storing-output-of-sql-query-in-python-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and now it worked

```
query2 ="""insert into table xyz(select * from abc where date_time = %s)"""
cur.execute(query2,(rows))
```

Though, I don't know why it worked and how is it different from what I was trying earlier