# Storing output of SQL Query in Python Variable

Tags: python, sql

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232171/sql-date-variables-in-python), I tried modifying my SQL query as follows:

```
query2 ="""insert into table xyz(select * from abc where date_time > %s and date_time <= ( %s + interval '1 hour'))"""
cur.execute(query2,(rows,rows))
```

It gave an error saying

```
function takes at most 2 arguments(3 given)
```

Is there any work around for this error?

Comment: What is the *full* traceback?

Comment: Please do not post same question again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Date Variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232171/sql-date-variables-in-python)

Comment: Its not the same question. It is an ddition to the question already asked by me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232171/sql-date-variables-in-python)

Comment: The answer you have posted to your own question has 1 rows variable compared to 2 - which is what you are asking here.

Comment: btw, your sql-statement is invalid

Comment: Yes,it does.And now I want to add two rows variable in the very same way but I am getting an error.

Comment: @Daniel..My bad..Corrected it.!!!.Typo.Pl ignore..

Answer (score 0):

There is something fishy about your query, it does not look right:

```
insert into table xyz
(select * from abc where date_time = %s and %s + interval '1 hour')
```

I would suggest:

```
insert into xyz (<columns of xyz>)
select <columns of abc> 
from abc 
where date_time > ?
```

The query have been edited so it should be:

```
insert into xyz (<columns of xyz>)
select <columns of abc> 
from abc 
where date_time > ? and date_time <= ? + interval '1 hour'
```

Now when you execute your query:

```
cur.execute(query2,(ts, ts))
```

The number of parameter markers (?) in the query string should be equal to the number of elements in the tuple .

If you are using %s in your query (not recomended) you can assign values to those variables with:

```
"""insert into xyz (<columns of xyz>)
   select <columns of abc> 
   from abc 
   where date_time > %s""" % (value)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?